# DateTime versus Two Time Zones?

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have a data table that stores events.  Events are saved with local time.  I am developing a form, where the user inputs a date and time in the past.  After filling out the form handful of times, I need to take those dates and times, and find the events that occurred at those times.

The problem is that the user is imputing their local time, not mine.  I can add a offset, or timezone selection.  But then I realized that Day Light savings time is going to make things not work.

I cannot change my data table date and time values.  Where I can convert their date and time to mine, while taking in consideration daylight savings?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered storing dates in UTC format. Meaning, let the user give you the date in UTC and store that in UTC (in sqlserver) and search based on UTC.

Comment: Might be easier to ask users for their local time and time zone, then convert to UTC on the back-end. Depends on the sophistication of the userbase. But I do agree UTC is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Premise*: I really think the ideal way to solve your problem is convert your stored datetimes to UTC, and then use that when you search.

But you said you can't change those, so using `ConvertTime` to convert them at request time is probably your best second option.

- [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382770(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find all the details you need.
- You might also want to give a look at [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/), which is quite useful when dealing with TimeZones and DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

As you are storing the event time as local time, you will always have problems with daylight savings time. For events where the time overlaps, it's impossible to tell if the event occured the first or second time that the local time had that value. You have already lost information by storing it as local time. If you would store the event time as UTC instead, it would be possible to avoid that daylight savings problem.

Without changing the data that you store, it's impossible to get around the daylight savings problems. The best you can do is to convert the time from the user's time zone to UTC, then to your local time. Example:

```
TimeZoneInfo TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones().Where(t => t.StandardName == "W. Europe Standard Time").Single();
DateTime utc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(inputTime);
DateTime local = utc.ToLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like MyDateTime.ToLocalTime() will work for you?

Check out the following article, it should help.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx